# Why does eclipse not resolve the maven plugin dependencies after it being added to the dependencies section?

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-eclipse-plugin

I just installed the maven eclipse plugin and all is great. I have tried creating my first mojo. After the setup, it has downloaded all the required dependencies.

Now what is troubling me is that Eclipse isn't able to resolve the `org.apache.maven.plugins` classes.

My pom.xml :

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.blah.dalm.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>assembly-mojo</artifactId>
  <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
  <name>Assembly Mojo</name>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <build>       
    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}</sourceDirectory>
    <!-- Plugin Configurations -->
    <plugins>
        <!-- Compiler plugin to use 1.6 -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.6</source>
              <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <!--  Dependencies  -->  
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

My mojo file AssemblyMojo.java:

```java
package com.blah.dalm.mojo;

import java.util.List;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException; // <-- This is where it says it cannot resolve the class or package.

/**
 * "Assemble Goal"
 * @goal assemble-goal
 * @author Husain Khambaty
 *
 */
public class AssemblyMojo { 
    /**
     * @parameter expression="${assembly.sourcePath}"
     * @required
     */
    private String sourcePath;

    /**
     * @parameter expression="${assembly.outputPath}"
     * @required
     */
    private String outputFilePath;

    /**
     * @parameter
     */

    private List<String> excludeList;
    /**
     * @parameter
     */

    private String filterRule;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException { // <-- And here

    }
}
```

It is unable to resolve the MojoExectionException class (therefore I believe it isn't able to find the rerquired jars, which I guess it is supposed to automatically fetch after the Eclipse-Maven integration).

When I build it, it builds just fine.

Comment: When you say it builds just fine, are you building using maven or Eclipse? I cannot see any dependency added specific to any mojo jar which might have the MojoExectionException  class.

Comment: Make sure maven-plugin-api.jar has successcully downoladed in your maven local repository and exist in classpath in Eclipse project.

Comment: Thank you @yorkw, your answer led me to the solution. I have put the answer below along with the working solution that I was expecting. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution :**

Thanks to @yorkw - his answer led me to the solution.

After installing the Maven-Eclipse plugin, and adding the dependencies in the pom.xml, it is automatically supposed to find those jars from the maven repository and add them in a "Maven Dependencies" section. This didn't happen when I did it (probably did something wrong).

After @yorkw answer, I added the jar and it worked. Just then I figured that I had already enabled the Dependencies. So just for the heck of it, I disabled them and enabled them again and suddenly out of no where the "Maven Dependenices" appeared. Phew.

(Note : I did try putting up screenshots - but I'm a newbie on StackOverflow and it wont allow me to post images yet.. I shall in time edit this post back and put the screen shots for others).